# How can I bind C-return with define-key and kbd?

Tags: key-bindings

I am able to bind <kbd>M + RET</kbd> with:

```
(define-key my-keys-mode-map (kbd "<M-RET>") 'my-function)
```

How can I bind <kbd>C + RET</kbd> with the above format?

I have tried:

- `kbd "<C-RET>"`
- `kbd "C-<RET>"`
- `kbd "C-RET"`

But none of these work.

If it is impossible with `define-key` and `kbd`, is there another way to bind <kbd>C + RET</kbd> in the mode `my-keys-mode-map`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need not *guess* how Emacs represents the key sequence that corresponds to your pressing and holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

You can instead ask Emacs itself to tell you. Just do `C-h k` followed by using those keys.  In my Emacs, with my keyboard, Emacs tells me this:

```
<C-return> runs the command ...
```

So I know that what I need to pass to `kbd` is the string `"<C-return>"`.

So, as @glucas says, I can use this (and you probably can too - but ask Emacs just how it sees those keys):

```
(define-key my-keys-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'my-function)
```

Comment: As I said in my comment on glucas's answer, my emacs only seems to see `<RET>` when I hit `C-return`. Do you have any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: You don't cite the actual text of the help output that you say indicates that Emacs sees only `<RET>`. Anyway, perhaps keys `Ctrl` + `Return` with your keyboard sends only what `Return` sends. Do other apps besides Emacs distinguish the key combination `Ctrl` + `Return` for you?

Comment: Emacs' output on `C-h k C-return`: "RET runs the command newline, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`. It is bound to RET." How do you recommend testing whether apps besides Emacs see C-return for me?

Comment: It sounds like your keyboard sends just `^M` (Control-M, aka RET) for `C-return`. If you are running Emacs in terminal mode that might be the case. Maybe you have another application where you can distinguish `C-return` from `RET`? Or maybe not.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
(define-key my-keys-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'my-function)
```

More generally, try using `describe-key` to see what Emacs "sees" for a given key combination. `C-h` followed by your key sequence (control + return) gives me:

```
<C-return> is undefined
```

So I can use `"<C-return>"` as the argument for `kbd`.

Comment: When I execute `M-x describe-key C-return`, is says it is bound to just RET. I can obviously use other control combinations, but emacs doesn't seem to recognize control combined with return. I am on Mac OS, using emacs 24.3.1 via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs

> `RET` -> for terminal mode
>
> `<return>` -> for GUI mode

So, you might be confusing the two.

Comment: What docs? It can be either key for either terminal or GUI, depending on the terminal. And this doesn't respond to a question about the key being modified with modifier key `Ctrl`.

Comment: could not find actual doc again but take a look at this http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_key_notation_return_vs_RET.html was the doc on my Ubuntu: (eval-after-load 'ensime 
     '(define-key ensime-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'ensime-inf-eval-region))          works fine.

Comment: The doc you link to is simply wrong. You can both keys or either key in either a terminal or a GUI session, depending on the terminal you use.